# get path of an uploaded file

Tags: file, drupal-7

This is my form to upload a photo

```
$form['Background_image'] = array(
'#type' => 'managed_file',
'#title' => t('Choose a background image'),
 '#description' => t('Click "Browse..." to select an image to upload.'),
'#required' => TRUE,
'#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('jpeg jpg png gif')),
'#upload_location' => 'public://backgroundimage/',
'#default_value' => $this->options['Background_image'],

);
```

I tried this function that get the current uploaded image and return its path, but still not working: what is missing:

```
 function image_path()
   {
    $f = file_load($this->options['Background_image']);
     //this too is not working: 
     //$f = file_load($form_state['values']['Background_image']);
      $url_image = file_create_url($f->uri);
      print_r($url_image);
      return ($url_image);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your value `$this->options['Background_image']` is the file id (a.k.a. fid) then the only issue I see with the second set of code is with your `print_r` statement. `file_create_url` returns a string, not an object or array, so you only have to print the output.

So replace:

```
print_r($url_image);
```

With:

```
print $url_image;
```

and it'll output the image's full url (including http) to the browser. Or simply remove the `print_r` statement if you are returning the value for use in another function.